# How to present entities in a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces

I have two tables: `question(id_question,id_form,id_type,question,count)` and `form(id_form,id_user,name,date_creation,start_date,end_date)`. I would like to show all questions. I have `id_form`. So how can I show all my question from question table if I have `id_form`.

This is what I have written so far:

Code from FormBean:

```
public String loadToView() {
    EntityManager em = DBManager.getManager().createEntityManager();
    this.form = em.find(Form.class, form.getIdForm());
    em.close();
    return "viewForm.xhtml";
}
```

I know that I have to somehow get question.
And I think on vieForm.xhtml I can use a DataTable form PrimeFaces UI. 
Can you give me some hand or provide how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Are question and form tables are linked in any way ??

Comment: What have you tried in XHTML and how exactly did that fail? PrimeFaces has a rather extensive showcase site full of examples, also those of `<p:dataTable>`.

Answer (score 0):

Since from your question it seems, there is many to one relationship between form table and question table.So what i understood is That is One form can have many question,to be more clear form id can be similar in question table.

In order to load all questions by calling em.find on Form class of JPA ,you need to map these entities in JPA.

In your case it would be :

```
 @Entity
public class Form{
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="form",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @MapKey(name="type")
  private Map<String, Question> question;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Question{
  @Id
  private long id;

  ...
  @ManyToOne
  private Form form;
  ...
}
```

In above enitities have getter and setter for the Map questions, you can use List as well in place of Map.

Comment: I have somehtning like your code, but the main problem for me is how I can get ID question if I have id_form ?

Comment: that is the role of cascade.All , when you'll do em.find passing id_form you will get table data including question table data for that id_form in question table. As i mentioned you need to create setter and getter of relationship.So when you'll do form.getQuestion this will give question data from form instance.